# Why can't I reference key in reduce logic?

Tags: python, mapreduce, pyspark

I want to have logic in my `combineByKey`/`reduceByKey`/`foldByKey` that relies on the key currently being operated on. From what I can tell by the method signatures, the only parameters passed to these methods are the values being combined/reduced/folded.

Using a simple example where I just have an RDD which is `(int, int)` tuples, the result I want is an rdd keyed by `tuple[0]` where the value is the `int` closest to the key.

For example:

```
(1, 8)
(1, 3)
(1, -1)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
(2, 2)
(3, 2)
(3, 4)
```

Should reduce to:

```
(1, 3)
(2, 2)
(3, 2)
```

Note in comparing `(1, 3)` and `(1, -1)` I don't care which one is picked since they are both the same distance. Same for the "3" key.

The way I would imagine doing this would be something along the lines of:

```
rdd.reduceByKey(lambda key, v1, v2: v1 if abs(key - v1) < abs(key - v2) else v2)
```

But the `reduce` function only takes 2 arguments: two values to be combined. It seems like the easiest method would be to reference the key in my reducer in order to achieve my goal; is this possible?

If I try this I get an error:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, 8), (1, 3), (1, -1), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 4)])
rdd.reduceByKey(lambda key, v1, v2: v1 if abs(key - v1) < abs(key - v2) else v2).collect()
```

> TypeError: () takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

I'm not really looking for a solution to this example problem. What I'm wondering is if there is a reason the key is not passed to the `reduceByKey` function? I assume it is some basic principle of the map-reduce philosophy that I am missing.

---

Note I can solve my example by inserting a map step which maps each value to a tuple consisting of the value and the distance from the key:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, 8), (1, 3), (1, -1), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 4)])
rdd = rdd.map(lambda tup: (tup[0], tuple([tup[1], abs(tup[0] - tup[1])])))
rdd.reduceByKey(lambda v1, v2: v1 if v1[1] < v2[1] else v2).mapValues(lambda x: x[0]).collectAsMap()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no strong reason not to pass keys.
however, I feel `reduceByKey` API was designed for common use case -- compute sum of values for each key.  So far I've never needed keys within the value computation.  But that's just my opinion.

Also the problem that you solved seems to be simple aggregation problem.  `min()` and `groupByKey` can find the answer. I know you are not looking for a solution but here is how I'd write.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, 8), (1, 3), (1, -1), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 4)])
reduced = rdd.groupByKey().map(lambda (k, v): (k, min(v, key=lambda e:abs(e-k))))
print(reduced.collectAsMap())
```

Result

```
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2}
```

Comment: Nice answer. It is very possible that the real answer to my question is simply "because that's not the API". But I was wondering about it anyways.